# Can a runner play events during the run?

Tags: android-netrunner

Can a runner play events during the run? Timing structure of a run says that paid abilities could be played. What about events?

Comment: No. "Play an event" is an "action". The card shown in the link is not a game card, actually. It does not participate in the game. It is just a reminder. You can play without it. "Paid ability" explained in the core rules on page 11: "Some card abilities have trigger costs that a player must pay before the effect of the ability can be resolved".

Comment: Yeah, good point. I worded it wrong. Using a click-costed card ability is an action. In any case, this is still fundamentally the same question, with the same answer. You can't perform one action in the middle of another action.

Comment: I do not sure that paid ability with a click in its cost is an action. The rules say that "... unless the ability requires a click, in which case it must be triggered as an action". It is not clear wheather such ability is actually an action or it is should be played as an action. It is different things. In the next sentance rules state than Magnus Opus paid ability is still ability ("An example of a paid ability is the Card Magnus Opus").

Comment: "Whenever the Runner spends clicks on one of these actions, he
is considered to be taking an action and cannot take another
action until the current action fully resolves."

Comment: Basically "cost: effect" is paid ability, but "click: effect" is also an action, and restrictions on action override restrictions on paid ability.

Comment: http://ancur.wikia.com/wiki/Core_Rule_Book#2._Action_Phase